# Kohya_SS errors "libcudart.so not found" "CUDA setup failed" "CalledProcessError"

Tags: cuda

I am getting errors when I am Lora training with Kohya_SS. I have it working fine on my Windows PC but am trying to switch to Linux (which I am brand new to). There are a few posts that I found here and on github but they are either a bit different than mine or way over my head. Thank you in advanced for any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am guessing that I did the images wrong because they are not showing up. If someone wanted to tell me how to get the images to show up instead of links, I would be happy to fix this post.